# Selenium grid 2 over cygwin

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, selenium-grid

Ok, this is a tricky one. I'm trying to set up a Selenium Grid 2 with some Windows 7 VMs to run Webdriver tests. To automatize the whole process I use some ant script that connects to the VMs through ssh to start/stop/reconfigure the nodes.

Everything works great, the nodes can register with the hub host and execute the test. Only problem is that I don't see any browser window during the test run. I can see the process and I see the test log being executed, but there is no graphical interface.

On the other hand, if I start the node manually through Windows, everything is normal.

I suppose the problem is that processes executed under cygwin cannot start Windows displays, but in that case, shouldn't throw an error? The other option I'm thinking is that Webdriver is using HTMLunit as a fallback, but then... why do I see the firefox process as long as the test lasts and consuming CPU and memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through ssh, you only exchange with Windows stdin, stdout and stderr streams. The ssh connection is tunneling those streams and nothing else. You don't see Windows Desktop interface, *but* the Desktop object exists on the Windows machine, the programs (here the browsers) are connected to it, and all GUI interactions are live in there.

1. If the GUI doesn't require any user interaction, everything is fine that way. The dialog boxes are created, the program runs, once it finishes, the dialog boxes are destroyed by the application and the application closes. Nothing is blocking in terms of GUI our application.
2. If you program requires an user action in the created yet invisible dialog boxes, your program will be there waiting for your interaction to move forward. You will see the process in the task manager, doing nothing but waiting. As you don't have access to the Windows Desktop where the dialog boxes are created and virtually 'displayed', the program seems to hang.

A typical case 2 is if you remote run a program waiting for a user to do something, say notepad. You can launch notepad, it will be spawned and then it will wait for you to type some text or close it.

With your Selenium tests, you are in case 1: all the browsers' interactions needed to make the GUI working are actually done by Selenium server that does the navigation clicks and the program exit for you. Their GUI actually are living by browsing through your test web servers, you just don't see it.

Some further readings from Microsoft website on [Desktops](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Desktop Creation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687105%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, quite educating! Actually everything is working, only issue that we have is when a test fails the screenshot taken is all black, and of course is a lot less convenient for debugging and see the errors. Would there be any workaround for this?

Comment: if you are running through this problem, it is a common issue. Google it and you will find several answers on stack overflow and other web sites. I can advise you that page that will give you several options. http://bharath-marrivada.blogspot.fr/2011/11/blackscreenshots-qtp-selenium-windows.html

Comment: But this problem only happens when the tests are executed in this "Desktop" object that I cannot see, starting the nodes manually in Windows everything works fine, so I assume none of those solutions can be applied in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the tests and have valid screenshots, you need to have a user logged in and those tests need to run as that user.  Everything must run through that single desktop session, so you cannot use RDP to remotely connect to the machine.  Your best bet is to use VNC, since that will connect to an already established session.